# Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n^{2}+3$. Prove that $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n^{2}+3$. Prove that $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$

Hint: $\left(\frac{n^2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)$

I know that this implies that $n^2\equiv -3\pmod p$ but beyond that I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you clarify your notation? Are those Legendre symbols in the hint or fractions or something else altogether?

Comment: Doesn't make sense as fractions, so Legendre. @AdamHughes

Comment: "I know that this implies..." Then you know wrong. $n^2\equiv -3\pmod p$.

Comment: $n=3$ is a counterexample with $p=3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks, I realized that after rereading. @_@

Comment: Yes I meant legendre symbols and you are right it should be -3.

Comment: Let $n$ be odd and let $p=2$...

Comment: I think the correct version of the question could be: "Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then, there is a prime divisor $p$ of $n^2+3$ with $p\equiv 1\mod 3$."

Comment: @LordSoth that is not correct for $ n = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume $p\ne 2,3$. (These cases can be investigated separately.)

Then $p\nmid n^2$, hence $\left(\frac{n^2}p\right)=1$. So we know that $$\left(\frac{-3}p\right)=1.$$

We have
$$\left(\frac{-3}p\right) = \left(\frac{-1}p\right)\left(\frac3p\right) = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\left(\frac{p}3\right)= \left(\frac{p}3\right).$$

So we get that $\left(\frac{p}3\right)=1$ which holds if and only 
$$ p \equiv 1 \pmod 3.$$

---

Related post: [Under what conditions does $(\frac{3}{p})(\frac{-1}{p})=1?$ Two ways, different results.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165807/under-what-conditions-does-frac3p-frac-1p-1-two-ways-different)

Answer (score 1):

Take $n=1$ and $n=3$ respectively to see that the claim does not hold for $p=2$ or $p=3$. So assume that $p \not \in \{2,3\}$.  Then $n^2 \not \in \{\overline{1}, \overline{9}\} \pmod p$ and therefore $2^{-1}(n-1)$ has order $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^{\ast}$. This implies that $3 \mid p-1$.

Comment: This works if $2^{-1}(n-1)\ne 1$. So it seems that $p=3=n$ is an exception. (Perhaps one should spend a moment looking also at the case $p\mid n-1$, since this argument implicitly assumes that remainder of $n-1$ is in $\mathbb F_p$. But this would be problem only for $p=2$.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks.  It needed a bit more thought.

Comment: [Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16690130#16690130) I wrote how I understood your argument (before your last edit).